# Horizontal FlatList inside ScrollView is not scrolling

Tags: android, react-native

I have a screen with many horizontal FlatLists inside a ScrollView, the structure is likes this:

```
<ScrollView>
  <View>
    <FlatList horizontal={true} .../>
  </View>
  <View>
    <FlatList horizontal={true} .../>
  </View>
  <View>
    <FlatList horizontal={true} .../>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Horizontal scrolling on each FlatList sometimes work, but most of the times happens a swipe to the next screen:

[image: gif]

Am using react native 0.61.2, react-navigation 4.0.10. Previously on react native 0.60.x works good. It only happens on android.

I already tried:

- put `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` on `<ScrollView>`
- put ScrollView inside a `<View>` with `flex:1`
- put `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` on `<ScrollView>` and on each `FlatList`

but it's not working, What more else can I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: the scroll conflict caused by the scroll tab. which scroll tab you use?

Comment: what if you remove the root scrollview and keep the flatlists in a view giving flex 1 to each flatlist so that the space is evenly distributed and see if it works that way.

Comment: @Lenoarod am using a MaterialTopTabNavigator

Comment: @WaheedAkhter I tried, but doesn't work

Comment: @Andres Lopez you can try react-native-scroll-tabView

Comment: @RoniCastro at the end it was a issue with react-native-gesture-handler, I was using the 1.4.1, but when I downgrade it to 1.3.0 it works. I hope that can helps you

Answer (score 4):

Have you used flatlist imported from react native gesture handler? Usually it happens that people import flatlist from react native and that cause that issue. When you work with react navigation it is mandatory to use flatlist from react-native-gesture-handler library in order to properly manage handlers interactions

Comment: What advantages have using the component from gesture handler instead of the default one? Is this in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this:

```
<ScrollView>
  <View>
    <FlatList horizontal .../>
  </View>
  <View>
    <FlatList horizontal .../>
  </View>
  <View>
    <FlatList horizontal .../>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

just pass horizontal props in  Components.
It will work.